# Magento 2 Multiple translations

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4, localisation

Is it possible to implement multiple translations in a "Magento 2" way?
I have a form on my website where I should have the same language text as a user browser language. How to achieve it?
As an example:
We have an English language store, where we have a form with the same recommendations for customers on language as on their browser's language.

Comment: magento has configuration where you can set local as per store view

Comment: @Pramod I want to use 2-3 languages translation for 1 store(as an example - English store).